# Determining JPG quality in Python (PIL)

Tags: python, image, jpeg

I am playing around with PIL library in Python and I am wondering how do I determine quality of given JPG image.  I try to open JPG image do something to it and save it again in the its original quality.  Image.save let me determine the desired quality:

```
im.save(name, quality = x)
```

but I can't see any way to extract original one. For now I am just guessing and try to have an output file of the same size as input by doing binary search on 'quality' parameter but this is not acceptable long term solution :)
I also tried using: Image.info but most of my images don't have any useful information there (ex: 'adobe', 'icc_profile', 'exif', 'adobe_transform')
Help !

Comment: Relevant info: http://superuser.com/questions/62730/how-to-find-the-jpg-quality/91083#91083

Comment: In general it's not possible to recover the precise quality value used to compress a JPEG file because there are various different ways of reducing the stored information and the quality value is only a guideline to the encoder but, as @unutbu points out, some software can make a heroic guess.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that JPEG is a lossy format so opening and saving an image will degrade the image quality even if the "quality" option is set to the same value.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In PIL (and mostly all softwares/librairies that use [libjpeg](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijg.org%2F&ei=xIv6TNbMOIyt8Ab8o-zvCg&usg=AFQjCNHslBwzbdmbbWUN8u4mM_MyAer7Cg&sig2=dJt01vTnHP5te7Qlb2zK2w)) the quality setting is use to construct the quantization table ([ref.](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libjpeg.jpeg.set.linear.quality.1.html)). In libjpeg the quality number "scale" the sample table values (from the JPEG specification Section K.1). In other librairies there's different tables assign to different qualities (ex.: Photoshop, digital camera).

So, in others terms, the quality equal to the quantization table, so it's more complex then just a number.

If you want to save your modify images with the same "quality", you only need to use the same quantization table. Fortunately, the quantization table is embeded in each JPEG. Unfortunately, it's not possible to specify a quantization table when saving in PIL. `cjpeg`, a command line utilities that come with libjpeg, can do that.

Here's some rough code that save a jpeg with a specified quantization table:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

proc = Popen('%s -sample 1x1 -optimize -progressive -qtables %s -outfile %s' % ('path/to/cjpeg', '/path/ta/qtable', 'out.jpg'), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
P = '6'
if im.mode == 'L':
    P = '5'
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('P%s\n%s %s\n255\n%s' % (P, im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tostring()))
```

You will need to find the way to extract the quantization table from the orginal jpeg. `djpeg` can do that (part of libjpeg):

```
djpeg -verbose -verbose image.jpg > /dev/null
```

You will need also to find and set the sampling. For more info on that check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Color_space_transformation). You can also look at [`test_subsampling`](http://hg.effbot.org/pil-2009-raclette/src/e9ec832e1dd2/Tests/test_file_jpeg.py)

**UPDATE**

I did a PIL fork to add the possibility to specify subsampling or quantization tables or both when saving JPEG. You can also specify `quality='keep'` when saving and the image will be saved with the same quantization tables and subsampling as the original (original need to be a JPEG). There's also some presets (based on Photoshop) that you can pass to quality when saving. [My fork.](https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/)

**UPDATE 2**

My code is now part of [Pillow 2.0](http://python-imaging.github.io/Pillow/). So just do:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: The quantization tables are also available in the `quantization` attribute of a `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile` (which is the type you get when you `Image.open` a JPEG file).

Comment: That's good to know. So the only thing missing in PIL is a way to specify (pass) the quantization table when saving.

Comment: Sweet, especially that it works with 3.3; I am happy you remembered this old question :)

Comment: `quality="keep"` does NOT work for me. I am using Pillow 2.5.1. Reported an issue on the Pillow Github repo. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/857 Can someone help, please?

Comment: Is im.save the equivalent to image_file.write and is there a way to parse save quality to .write ?

Comment: still, imagemagick seems to use [heuristics](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/coders/jpeg.c#L779) to compute a rough Quality number. it would be nice to have the same in Pillow

Comment: @eddygeek What would be the advantage of using heuristics to compute a rough Quality number instead of using exactly the same quantization table as the original?

Comment: @Etienne you are correct in the context of this question (copying/transforming a jpeg). I was talking more generally quality is a great concise proxy for both image degradation and image size, eg to choose whether to further compress the image, so just saying "it would be nice to have the same in Pillow" overall (*not* for the OP). see my answer with code below.

Comment: Oh, it took me a moment to understand what you have written, but now I get it! Yes, it could be useful to be able to compute the "quality number" of a JPEG from its quantization tables to take some decisions. You can propose your implementation to Pillow.

Answer (score 4):

Quality is something that is used to generate the data that is stored in the JPEG.  This number is not stored in the JPEG.

One way that you might be able to determine quality is to take the topleft 8x8 pixel cell of the image before you edit it and run the JPEG compression formula on just that to get close to the original.  You need to develop a distance function from the result of that to your original (pixel difference).

You will still be doing a binary search with quality, but it's a much smaller amount of work.

Here is information on how JPEG compression works

https://www.dspguide.com/ch27/6.htm

Here's another way from a MS FAQ

[https://support.microsoft.com/kb/324790](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328083839/http://support.microsoft.com:80/en-us/kb/324790)

You have to translate from C#.

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues using `quality='keep'` in combination with some PIL operations, because for example during `rotate()` or `transpose()`, a new Image instance is being created, which loses some properties, like `format` and `quantization`.

I had to look into the Pillow source to figure it out, but it seems you can also do it like this:

```
def _save_image_matching_quality(img, original_img, fp):
    frmt = original_img.format

    if frmt == 'JPEG':
        quantization = getattr(original_img, 'quantization', None)
        subsampling = JpegImagePlugin.get_sampling(original_img)
        quality = 100 if quantization is None else -1
        img.save(fp, format=frmt, subsampling=subsampling, qtables=quantization, quality=quality)
    else:
        img.save(fp, format=frmt, quality=100)
```

It should do everything that `quality='keep'` does :)

This exact code may not be suitable for each use case though, and you might have to tweak it. What I was trying to achieve is saving as much space possible, but without affecting the image quality as the highest priority.

For a general use case, this might be better:

```
def _save_image_matching_quality(img, original_img, fp):
    frmt = original_img.format

    if frmt == 'JPEG':
        quantization = getattr(original_img, 'quantization', None)
        subsampling = JpegImagePlugin.get_sampling(original_img)
        img.save(fp, format=frmt, subsampling=subsampling, qtables=quantization)
    else:
        img.save(fp, format=frmt)
```

Comment: The `quality = 100 if quantization is None else 0` did not work for me. Left it out.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker in the latest version of Pillow, it should be `quality = 100 if quantization is None else -1` as they've made some internal changes.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that the original quality number is only used by the library to compute the quantization tables, *ImageMagick* uses a [heuristic](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/7.1.0-57/coders/jpeg.c#L782) to compute an approximation of the quality from the quantization tables (maybe assuming `libjpeg` or similar was used for encoding).

Here is a port of this heuristic to python: [jpg_quality_pil_magick.py](https://gist.github.com/eddy-geek/c0f01dc5401dc50a49a0a821cdc9b3e8#file-jpg_quality_pil_magick-py)

Use:

```py
    from PIL import Image
    from jpg_quality_pil_magick import get_jpg_quality
    pim = Image.open(...)
    quality = get_jpg_quality(pim)
```

For lossless image processing, you should rather use `quality='keep'` as @Etienne said.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested quality='keep' keyword with PIL 5.1. It produces exactly the same result as default quality which is 75.

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('yy.jpg')
img.save('xx.jpg', quality='keep')
img.save('xx1.jpg', quality=75)
img.save('xx2.jpg') # no quality keyword so default is applied

import sh
for i, f in enumerate(('yy.jpg', 'xx1.jpg', 'xx2.jpg')):
    try:
        a = ('xx.jpg', f)
        r = sh.diff(*a)
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode as e:
        r = e.stdout
    r = r.rstrip()
    r = r if r else 'are the same'
    print i, a, r
```

Answer (score -5):

As far as I understood you, this is not possible. The JPEG format is compressed by removing 75% of the color data, or by simplifying colors. There is no way to make the color quality higher.

Comment: JPEG does not "compress by removing 75% of the color data, or by simplifying colors."  It does do a colorspace conversion to a more efficient colorspace (YCbCr), but that's just the first step.

Comment: FYI: JPEG commonly does compress by removing 75% of the color data (4:2:0 subsampling).

Comment: Chroma subsampling is not predefined. You can have JPEG with whatever chroma subsampling you want. Most implementations have 4:2:0 subsampling as default, because it makes sense - our vision is sharper on the BW channel than on the chroma channels. But JPEG images can also have 4:4:4 (no subsampling) or whatever other subsampling. Setting subsampling=0 in PIL should turn off subsampling.