# Preserving image type info in PIL when cropping

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I am using the excellent modification to Python's PIL by Etienne [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355281/1264727). What I need is exactly what the modification does - to save a JPEG file using the same quantization tables as the original. Doing it through that modification seems elegant, I'm currently achieving that by using a hodgepodge of C code.

My problem is that I get a JPEG file object in PIL, but after any modification it becomes an object of some other type. What I want is to take the image, crop it and save it with the same quantization table.

I try:

```
img = Image.open("someimage.jpg")
width, height = img.size
crop = img.crop((8, 0, width, height))
img = img.resize((width - 8, height))
img.paste(crop, (0,0))
img.save("crop.jpg", quality='keep')
```

The img object is first a PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile but becomes just an Image after the resize/paste operation. So consequently I can't use quality='keep' as it's no longer a JPEG. I've tried cropping and pasting as above, I tried a few other ways but nothing seems to preserve the JpegImageFile object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [this fork by Etienne](https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/changesets), which I think you are, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
img = Image.open("someimage.jpg")
qt = img.quantization
# qt is now a dictionary of arrays which is your quantization table.

width, height = img.size
crop = img.crop((8, 0, width, height))
img = img.resize((width - 8, height))
img.paste(crop, (0,0))

# pass qt in as you save your jpeg
img.save("crop.jpg",  qtables = qt)
```

See [this documentation by Etienne](https://bitbucket.org/etienned/pil-2009-raclette/changeset/d6f15d93350d) for more info.

Comment: Ahh, I stupidly did not imagine to check within the .py files for documentation. This works with a minor change - have to supply `enumerate(qt)` and not just `qt` for the `qtables` argument.

Comment: And it's also useful to create entire presets using both subsampling and quantization tables, as shown in the fork's JpegPresets.py file. Thanks!