# Rotating an image retailing its internals usin PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to rotate a PIL image while not knowing beforehand what type will it be and I want to retain the image internals such as it's quantization tables so I'll be able to write it exactly as it was in case I'll only change the Exif data).

The code I was using was:

```
from PIL import Image

pil_img = Image.open(image_filename)
pil_img = pil_img.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
exif_bytes = code_to_alter_the_exif(pil_img)
if pil_img.format == 'JPEG':
    pil_img.save(image_filename, "jpeg", exif=exif_bytes, quality='keep', optimize=False)    
elif pil_img.format == 'SOME OTHER FORMAT':
    pil_img.save(image_filename, "OTHER FORMT", other_formats parameters)
```

However, the output of transpose in `pil_img = pil_img.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)` is of type PIL.Image.Image, ant it no longer has any of the internal attributes.

Is there a way only to change the internal pixels of `pil_img`?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672442/preserving-image-type-info-in-pil-when-cropping) combined with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354543/determining-jpg-quality-in-python-pil/4355281#4355281) can give me a solution specific to JPEG, but will not work in case of other formats.

Answer (score 0):

A pil image has a method rotate, so you can just do: `pil_img.rotate(90)`

Comment: If pil_img is of type JpegImageFile, pil_img.rotate(90) is of type PIL.Image.Image.
This means that you will lose all type-specific data that is contained in pil_img.