# Python PIL jpeg quality

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I use python to save jpegs in a smaller quality

```
im = Image.open(file)
im.save(cached_file, quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

In some images however, the file size of the new image is larger than the original's. How can this happen?

Comment: Providing an example where this is the case would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining JPG quality in Python (PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354543/determining-jpg-quality-in-python-pil)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible that the original image was saved with quality < 80? So, you are basically using more space to save artifacts of the reconstruction?

Comment: Is there a way to determine the quality of the original image and proceed with the process only if it is smaller?

Comment: I just looked at some PIL documentation - http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm It looks as though the default quality is 75, which would suggest that if you read an image that had been saved by PIL without a quality specifcation, the situation I hypothesized might occur. Apparently, when reading a JPEG, the quality is not known. I suspect the only way to know in advance is to learn more about JPEG encoding. Perhaps you would be OK with comparing the new saved file to the original and then deciding which one to keep?

Comment: Actually, I have thought about what you are suggesting and possibly will follow it, but I thought I'd ask to see if there is a more optimal way to handle it. Thanks