# How to find the size of an image in bytes using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I couldn't find anyway to print the size of an image in bytes.

Comment: Images are files too. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: [here you can find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904141/6075699) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904141/6075699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `os`.

```
import os
os.path.getsize('test.jpg')
```