# How to know the Image filesize without storing locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program that merges two image not stored in local, this third image, the merged one, is a PIL Image, I need to check the image filesize and, if it is over a certain size, I need to compress it.

This is my code:

```
def concat_image_auto(image1,image2,size_image):
    if size[0]>size[1]:
        ## vertical
        dst = Image.new('RGB', (size_image[0], image1.height + image2.height))
        dst.paste(image1, (0, 0))
        dst.paste(image2, (0, image1.height))
    else:
        ## horizontal
        dst = Image.new('RGB', (image1.width + image2.width, size_image[1]))
        dst.paste(image1, (0, 0))
        dst.paste(image2, (image1.width, 0))
    return dst


image1 = Image.open('my_first_image.jpg')     
image2 = Image.open('my_second_image.jpg') 

max_w = max(image1.size[0],image2.size[0])
max_h = max(image1.size[1],image2.size[1])
size = (max_w,max_h)
image1 = image1.resize(size)
image2 = image2.resize(size)

#Merging
file_merged = concat_image_auto(image1,image2,size)

#Check filesize and compress if needed
```

How can I do that?
(I can't save the image in memory)

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer I think the OP refers to the bytesize of the image, not its (width,height)

Comment: Oh right, sorry. In that case, does the answer by ady on this similar question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904083/how-to-get-image-size-bytes-using-pil

Comment: I don't need W and H values, but The filesize in Kb or Mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the image in memory, and then see how big the result is:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    file_merged.save(output, format="PNG")
    size = output.getbuffer().nbytes
```

Because you use `with` the data is discarded afterwards

Comment: I can't save the image in memory

Comment: And why is that? Please be more specific. Do you get an error? Is the image very large and you don't have enough memory?

Comment: Because I'm working on AWS Lambda, I can't store locally until I don't finish the job. When the compressed image is ready I have to store it in S3 bucket.

Comment: Yes. This code doesn't store it locally, on a disk/filesystem, which you can't use on Lambda. It stores it in memory, which you can use all you want on a Lambda

Comment: Ok, but I get this error: module 'io' has no attribute 'getbuffer'

Comment: Now that is an actual issue. It stemmed from a typo in my answer. It is fixed now. Please try again

Comment: U ciunn d quera ciucc d sort. Thank you very much! :)