# Want to get image size in kilobytes using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I am trying to get the image name, resolution, and size of the image from the directory. I got image name, resolution and size but image size is not in kilobytes it is getting like pixels. so please suggest me how to get the image size with the python script.

```
    # Required Libraries
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from pathlib import Path
import numpy
import cv2
import argparse
import numpy
import csv
from PIL import Image
  
# Check whether the CSV 
# exists or not if not then create one.
my_file = Path("csv/details.csv")
  
if my_file.is_file():
    f = open(my_file, "w+")
    with open('csv/details.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
          
        writer.writerow(["S.No.", "Name", "Resolution", "Size"
                        ])
    f.close()
    pass
    
else:
    with open('csv/details.csv', 'w', newline = '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
          
        writer.writerow(["S.No.", "Name", "Resolution", "Size"
                        ])
  
# Argparse function to get
# the path of the image directory
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", 
                required = True, 
                help = "Path to folder")
  
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
  
# Program to find the
# colors and embed in the CSV
mypath = args["image"]
  
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = numpy.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype = object)
  
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
    
    path = join(mypath,onlyfiles[n])
    images[n] = cv2.imread(join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]),
                           cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
      
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    h,w,c = img.shape
    resolution = f"{h} X {w}"
    size = img.size
    print(h, w)
      
    avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis = 0)
    avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis = 0)
      
    with open('csv/details.csv', 'a', newline = '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([n+1, onlyfiles[n], resolution, size  
                        ])
        file.close()
```

and also please find below is the screenshot for your reference.[image]

Comment: First google hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904083/how-to-get-image-size-bytes-using-pil
Does that help?

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you make a running example script focused just on the thing you are having problems with? I noticed you do `size = img.size`, is that the size you are talking about? That would be image size, not the file size.

Comment: As an aside, you can use `Path` to replace `listdir`, `isfile` and `join` - its considered a replacement for the path functions in `os`.

Comment: Yes, I am getting image size but I want to get file size.

Comment: 102flowers/images\image_08176.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08177.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08178.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08179.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08180.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08181.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08182.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08183.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08184.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08185.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08186.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08187.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08188.jpg
102flowers/images\image_08189.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use this inside your for loop

```
import os

file_size = os.path.getsize('d:/file.jpg')
print("File Size is :", file_size, "bytes")
```

Comment: Hi @lamourette jean-baptiste, thanks for the reply, i am getting error like  return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'path

Comment: Are you sure of the path provided ? is it a relative or an absolute one ?
Can you try to put complete path ?

Comment: don't just copy-paste code. that's not how programming works. you need to change the path to some file that exists!

Comment: Hi @lamourette jean-baptiste, it works for me, by keeping this code os.path.getsize('d:/file.jpg') at size variable, Thank you.