# Why does resizing a JPEG image using PIL, increases file size?

Tags: python, image-processing, jpeg, python-imaging-library, wand

I have written a Python code which resizes an image into a max 1200 x 1200 frame, maintaining the aspect ratio. I am coming across this case where the input image(1080 x 1350) is 249.8KB whereas the output image(960 x 1200) is 317.2KB. This is happening in spite of `optimize = True` and maintaining the quality. My code is as below:

```
from PIL import Image
from wand.image import Image as Wand

MAX_RES = 1200
photo = Image.open("input.jpg")
breadth,height = photo.size
qual = Wand(filename="input.jpg").compression_quality
if(not((breadth <= MAX_RES) and (height <= MAX_RES))):
    resizeRatio = max (float(breadth)/MAX_RES, float(height)/MAX_RES)
    photo = photo.resize((int(breadth/resizeRatio),int(height/resizeRatio)))
    photo.save("output.jpg",optimization = True,quality=qual)
```

Using `Image.ANTIALIAS` increases the size even more.

Comment: Do you know for certain what the original JPEG settings were? (quality  etc.)

Comment: File size of a compressed image is not directly related to image size. A compression method can be less efficient when you modify the image, even a simple resize.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, how does one know that on an Ubuntu machine? I have the file on my hard-disk

Comment: @SagnikSinha I'm not familiar with PIL but there's an extensive answer on  that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354543/determining-jpg-quality-in-python-pil)

Comment: @SagnikSinha You can find out image properties using the [`identify` command-line tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php). It is possible that your original image had a lower quality than the resized one.

Comment: @user4815162342, I am getting the quaity using `wand` and you can see in the code, `Wand(filename="input.jpg").compression_quality`. Even after maintaining the quality and reducing the size, the output file size ends up larger than that of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors that affect JPEG compression:

1. Subsampling of Cb and Cr components.
2. Quantization tables use (sometimes dumbed down to "quality" settings)
3. Whether optimized huffman tables are used.

It is highly likely your input settings were much different from the output settings.