# Mogrify decreases image filesize when adding an exif comment

Tags: image, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm having problems opening up certain jpeg files (ones from Facebook and Instagram, and some Samsung phones) in Photoshop. I've read that if I use `mogrify -comment test insert-image-here.jpg`, it will "handle" the file and somehow it'll open up in Photoshop. And surprisingly, it works very well.

However, I recently "mogrified" an image using the same above command, only to have the filesize go down by 0.71mb, which was alarming as I don't want to recompress my images in jpeg. I then mogrified it ten more times, but I didn't see any obvious visual losses. I tried "mogrifying" a small 170kb image 20 times, and the filesize initially decreased, then increased every subsequent iteration. I compared the files by swapping between them quickly, but didn't see any quality loss.

What is mogrify doing that is decreasing the filesize, seemingly without reducing the quality? Is there a quality option that I can add to make mogrify not reduce the filesize?

This is a similar question from another user [Why does the size of my image decrease when I add a comment to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321166/why-does-the-size-of-my-image-decrease-when-i-add-a-comment-to-an-image) but I cannot discern any quality loss whatsoever, so running my image through at 95 or 70% quality 20 times would be immediately noticeable.

Here is the link to the image that I am using as a test: http://ocicat.wildrain.tripod.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/aragon.jpg

Edit:

I ran two more images through the mogrify command 1000 times (one of white noise which I didn't include.) I still don't see any quality loss--is JPEG compression that unnoticeable (maybe my eyes are failing me.) Interestingly, the final file size and the original file size of these two images are the same.

Zero iterations:
[image]

1000 iterations:
[image]

Comment: I note that Safari on my iPad can't load that image either without error. Do you know what program created it? Or where it came from? I am suggesting the better solution might be not to generate problematic images in the first place rather than worrying about the *"correction"* causing new problems...

Comment: @Mark Setchell Well, the images that I get are only available from Instagram or Facebook (unfortunately.) They open up 100% fine in almost all image editors I've tried, except Photoshop. I would use Camera Raw to open them (which works) but has recently completely frozen the computer. I just found that very large image file of a cat for an example to see if mogrify was reducing images filesize by a fixed amount or by a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you would have trouble opening a JPG from those sources. But some viewers will not handle CMYK jpg files properly. I would be surprised if Photoshop has that problem. If you use Imagemagick to add a comment, then it will decompress your file and recompress it. Imagemagick will use the -quality value in the file if it can find it and make the output the same. However, if it cannot find the quality value in the file, then it will compress at value 92. That could cause a decrease in the file size if it was at 100 as input but was recompressed at 92. The next time you do the same it will continue to use 92. However, there might be some loss of effective quality because JPG is lossy. But at 92 it probably will not be visually noticeable. You could try convert in place of mogrify and see if that is any different. Also there is no need to add a comment. Just reading the input and saving it again will decompress and recompress it in Imagemagick. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

Your image is sRGB and has a quality of 75 according to Imagemagick

```
identify -verbose Aragon.jpg

Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 9600x14400+0+0
  Resolution: 2400x2400
  Print size: 4x6
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
...
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 75
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2017-08-18T21:26:37-07:00
    date:modify: 2017-08-18T21:26:37-07:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: bad15aa674dc45312d47627b620c895ee76b1fa4457b55bf1acca85883de5963
  Artifacts:
    filename: aragon.jpg
    verbose: true
```

So the CMYK issue is not present.

Is this file before or after you processed it with Imagemagick mogrify?

If this file was originally quality 75 and was recompressed at 92 or some higher value than 75, then it might increase in file size.

If you do not want the file size to decrease then recompress at 75 or higher. 100 would give you the least compression, but may increase the file size.

Other factors could be a change is -sampling-factor for the JPG. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sampling-factor. Also there could be a difference in the compression tables. Imagemagick use libjpg to read and decompress JPGs. The original JPG may have been compressed using other tools.

Another factor might be the introduction or removal of a color profile. Imagemagick should not be changing that automatically.

My best suggestion is to check the quality of the input and what quality is assigned to the output. Also check the input colorspace. Use identify -verbose yourimage to see what may have changed.

Unfortunately, I do not know exactly what is happening. I can only tell you some of the factors that may be involved.

I used Imagemagick 6.9.9.7 Q16 Mac OSX to convert your file.

```
convert aragon.jpg aragon2.jpg
```

The input has Filesize: 5.94157MiB. The output has Filesize: 5.23264MiB. Both files have the same quality 75. So there is a slight change in file size due to decompression and recompression, probably due to actual loss in quality due to the fact that JPG has a lossy compression. Or perhaps due to a change in compression tables used. Doing it once more yields a Filesize: 5.23289MiB. So a very slight increase. Doing

```
convert aragon.jpg -quality 100 aragon4.jpg
```

Yields a Filesize: 13.968MiB, since we have asked it to use a larger compression quality than the input, so the file size will increase dramatically even though it is a lossy compression.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! I don't know who owns aragorn.jpg, but I don't think it was compressed using mogrify before. The filesize reduction seems to be present on any image I try from a google search, so aragorn.jpg is just a large file for testing.