# Why does PIL (pillow) Image.save() reduce file size?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to rotate some images, and I noticed that the output file is much smaller, so I tried a test:  Do nothing to the file, except save the exif info (because I know that PIL Image will by default not save the exif info).  So here is my test code:

```py
    from PIL import Image
    test = Image.open('my_image_file.jpg')
    holdexif = test.info["exif"]
    test.save('my_saved_image_file.jpg',"jpeg",exif=holdexif)
```

When I do the above `my_saved_image_file.jpg` is significantly smaller (`441 KB`) than the original `my_image_file` (`1.83 MB`).  **Why is that?**  What is missing?

When I look at various properties of both files, they appear to be identical.  Both are 56 inches x 27 inches, both are 72 Pixels per inch, both are 4032 x 1960 pixels.  **I am by no means an expert when it comes to image files.**  Based on these things that I have examined (size, resolution, and the appearance of the images) the files appear to me to be the same.  From what I can see/understand, only the file size on disk is different.  What else should I be looking at?  What else may be different?

I also tried the `quality=` kwarg in the save:

```py
    test.save('my_saved_image_file.jpg',"jpeg",exif=holdexif,quality=95)
```

which gave me a file (`1.73 MB`) almost as large as the original (`1.83 MB`).  But I have no idea what is different to account for the larger size (and I don't understand what makes the "quality" better; the images appear the same to me).  I am trying to understand what exactly is different between the two files, so that I can make a decision.  Perhaps the smaller size is perfectly fine for my purposes.

Comment: The `PIL`s IMAGE is doing the compression.
you can check https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L60 here

Comment: Thanks.  Is the compression causing any loss of actual quality?  It doesn't appear to me.  But as I mentioned, for quality I only know to look at the size, resolution, and appearance to my eye on the screen.  Is there anything lost in the compression?  If so, what.  Thanks.

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/image-diff Let's try checking here. In the `difference` tab,

Comment: I'm reading the code, trying to find how it decodes the image from file and putting it back as a file.

Comment: Thanks.  That diffchecker is nice, but it shows no differences (using quality=95%, will try some other levels).  I am also reading this to see if I can understand the effect of compression better: http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-estq.php   Apparently there is some loss with the compression, it just may not be obvious to the eye.

Comment: https://medium.com/breaktheloop/jpeg-compression-algorithm-969af03773da this might be a helpful resource

Comment: @CharanjitSingh Thanks again.  Looks good.  I also just found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354543/determining-jpg-quality-in-python-pil  It appears that I can save with `qualtiy='keep'` to get the exact same level of compression as the original file.

Comment: The difference is invisible to human eye, I tried using a random image from the internet.
Initially, it was `72.8 kb`, I opened and closed it from PIL, the size `decreased` to `42kb` then I set the quality=95, The Size `Increased` to `120kb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, as Charanjit pointed out, is in the amount of compression (which is controlled with the `quality` kwarg of the `.save()` method).  More compression means a smaller file and less "quality".

Regarding "quality", this means that, *although the image size and image resolution may be the same*, the crispness of object edges, and color differentiation, within the image, will be reduced (possibly not apparent to the eye) by compression.

There is a good discussion of jpeg compression here: [Understanding JPEG Quality](http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-estq.php).

There is also another stackoverflow answer that addresses the issue of trying to save jpeg file with the same quality as the original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355281/1639359 by setting kwarg `quality='keep'` (instead of `quality=N` where `N` is an integer between 1 and 100 %).