# Why does the number of bytes in this buffer change from the original size when dealing with images?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

So i'm looking at some image resizing code in our code base, and i've noticed that after passing an image through PIL the number of bytes of the image increases by just under 2x.

I've gutted most of the code out for the purpose of this demonstration just so I could isolate the case:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


def size_test(content_file: ContentFile):
    with content_file.open("rb") as file:
        file_bytes = file.read()
        print("original size of bytes: %s" % len(file_bytes))

        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_bytes), formats=["JPEG"])

        with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
            image.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
            buffer_bytes = buffer.getvalue()

        print("new size of bytes: %s" % len(buffer_bytes))
```

Calling the above with the following code, loading in a JPEG file of known size:

```
with open('10mb.jpg', 'rb') as file:
    cf = ContentFile(file.read())


utils.size_test(cf)
```

Here is the output:

```
original size of bytes: 10174706
new size of bytes: 19538695
```

Maybe i'm missing something glaringly obvious, but i'm not sure what makes this image's bytes increase by 9MB in memory, unless it's to do with JPEG compression? Maybe by loading the JPEG into memory we are uncompressing it?

Just tried this with a 1.7MB PNG file (changing the relevant formats in the original function):

```
def size_test(content_file: ContentFile):
    with content_file.open("rb") as file:
        # load into Image object
        file_bytes = file.read()
        print("original size of bytes: %s" % len(file_bytes))
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_bytes), formats=["PNG"])
        with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
            image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
            data = buffer.getvalue()
        print("new size of bytes: %s" % len(data))
```

The opposite occurs:

```
original size of bytes: 1701968
new size of bytes: 1331325
```

What is going on here?

Comment: you could try passing `quality="keep"` when saving the file, otherwise it'll go with default settings.  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-saving

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PIL (pillow) Image.save() reduce file size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483536/why-does-pil-pillow-image-save-reduce-file-size)

Comment: I'll give `quality="keep"` a go, and that link is helpful, thanks :)