# Tell() method from io.BytesIO not returning the correct image weight

Tags: python, io, python-imaging-library

Whenever I call `os.path.getsize(file)`, it gives me the correct size. When images overshoot a fixed weight, I have to make transformations on it then ask the weight of the new image.

I have a very basic function to return the weight of an image. The reason is that I'd like to avoid going through the file system.

```
def get_weight(image: Image, img_format: str) -> int:
    out = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(out, format=img_format)
    return out.tell()
```

From what I understand, it copies the content of the image via a byte stream, then return the position. I'm assuming from its name that the stream buffer size is one byte, thus `position == image weight in bytes`.

It doesn't work consistently with JPEG format. I have images that gets their weight underestimated by 20% (in the 4 to 8 MB range).

Why is that so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `quality` in `Image.save()` is set to `75` by default.

If the image originally has a higher quality than 75, the weight may be underestimated. The opposite is true if the original quality is below 75, its weight may be overestimated.

From this [anwer about JPEG quality in Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355281/10409093), it is possible to keep the original quality of the image by setting quality to `"keep"`. Doing that will reproduce the original byte stream of the image, with a more similar length.